# content of iframe not responsive

Tags: html, css, iframe

I made an example here:

http://secure-wildwood-74891.herokuapp.com/

That page has two iframes.  The content in both of them, if opened in their own tab, in a window 414px wide (iphone 6s) will respect that width and render a responsive view.

That isn't happening in the first frame.  The content is rendering as if the browser is significantly wider than what the iframe is set to (400px wide).

The iframes both have scrollable="no" set already.

So, how do I make the content of the top one properly respect it's parent window size?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/masau/7wrhm/

Comment: @silviagreen works with your youtube example, but not the example in my testcase

Comment: @silviagreen http://jsfiddle.net/7WRHM/6343/

Comment: The problem is the site contained in the iframe, it is not responsive unfortunately

Comment: You can verify it simply resizing the the sbrowser window

Comment: Is the issue then that the iframe isn't appropriately scaling the content?

Comment: No, the content itself is the problem. Open https://actionnetwork.org/forms/atu-member-presidential-poll in your browser and then resize the browser. You will see that the site is not responsive